# Using select class with Flask

Tags: forms, flask, bootstrap-4

I want to retrieve in my python app the selected value in a html/javascript form.

Here is my html code :

```html
{% block content %}
<form method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="title">Numéro</label>
       <input type="number" name="NUMERO"
              placeholder="666, etc" class="form-control" required
              value="{{ request.form['NUMERO'] }}"/>
   </div>
<div class="form-group">
       <label for="TYPE_VOIE">Type voie</label>
       <select class="form-control" id="TYPE_VOIE" required >
          <option>Rue</option>
          <option>Impasse</option>
          <option>Place</option>
          <option>Boulevard</option>
          <option>Avenue</option>
      </select>  value="{{ request.form['TYPE_VOIE'] }}"
</div>
```

Here is python code:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        numero=int(request.form['NUMERO'])
        type_voie= request.form['TYPE_VOIE']
```

and now the error message:

> werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser
> (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
> KeyError: 'TYPE_VOIE' ...

In fact, I don't know where to put `value="{{ request.form['TYPE_VOIE'] }}"`

Can you help me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you forgot `</form>`...?

Comment: To prevent something like this from happening if it got through debugging, you could use `request.form.get("TYPE_VOIE")` which won't crash, just return `None`.

Comment: And your `value="{{ request.form["TYPE_VOIE"] }}"` should be an attribute of the `select` tag (if that was where you wanted it), so would go where things like `class` and `id` attributes go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a **name** attribute to your combo box like you did for the text box, thus:

```
<select class="form-control" id="TYPE_VOIE" name="TYPE_VOIE" required >
```

Basically, Flask does not "see" a form field named 'TYPE_VOIE' in your POST request.

Comment: Thanks you very much....In my form, do I delete all attributes value="..." ?

Comment: On the contrary you should have value tags for all your form fields, if you want to retrieve their values in the POST request.